# Problems with plotting vector files after raster in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a raster RGB with a vector file on the top.

```
### PLOTTING MAPS:
data_vector <- st_read("~/Desktop/TramsTenes2.gpkg")

##  PLOTIN' RGBs RASTERS:
orto <- brick("~/Desktop/of25mtif1676931256706.tif")
names(orto) = c("r","g","b")
orto_df <- as.data.frame(orto, xy = TRUE)
```

If I plot my raster chunk:

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_raster(data = orto_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = rgb(r = r, g = g, b = b, maxColorValue = 255)),show.legend = FALSE) + scale_fill_identity()
```

It works well!

If I plot the vector chunk it also works well!

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = data_vector, aes(fill = Seccio), lwd = 0.001) + scale_fill_identity()
```

But if I put it together:

```
    ggplot() + 
      geom_raster(data = orto_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = rgb(r = r, g = g, b = b, maxColorValue = 255)),show.legend = FALSE) + scale_fill_identity() +
  new_scale_color() +
      geom_sf(data = data_vector, aes(fill = Seccio), lwd = 0.001) + scale_fill_identity()
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `geom_sf()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error:
! colours encodes as numbers must be positive
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I think it has to do with aes but I am not sure. I tried with `inherit.aes = F` but any result so far.

Comment: We can't give you any direct help without a reproducible example, but it seems likely that your problem is that you have already used the fill scale to color the raster. This means you cannot map a numeric variable to the fill aesthetic in your second layer (and it seems you are trying to map a numeric variable to an identity scale, which doesn't make sense). You can fix this using `new_scale_fill` from the `ggnewscale` package. If you can't figure this out, please post a reproducible example so we can show you the actual code you need.

Comment: Thanks Allan! I tried that approach but couldn't manage. I prepared the vector file and the raster to be downloaded here: https://soccatherp.org/esborrar/

Comment: sorry 'cos I dont know how to make it reproducible (the vector file and the raster) without sharing the files themselves!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ggnewscale`, we can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

orto_df <- terra::rast("of25mtif1676931256706.tif") |>
  as.data.frame(xy = TRUE) |>
  setNames(c("x", "y", "r", "g", "b"))

data_vector <- sf::st_read("TramsTenes2.gpkg")

ggplot(orto_df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = rgb(r = r, g = g, b = b, maxColorValue = 255))) + 
  scale_fill_identity() +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_sf(data = data_vector, 
          aes(geometry = geom, fill = factor(seccio)), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d("Seccio")
```

[image]